# Conditional Logic inside of HTACCESS based on local develop ip (MAMP)

Tags: .htaccess

My htacces file has the following command in it forcing a web site to SSL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However the problem I have is that on my local MAMP server, if I go to localhost.domain.com in the browser I get redirected to domain.com.

Is there any conditional logic I can use in htaccess to say "if the request is from localhost then dont force redirect to ssl on the main domain"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add another `RewriteCond` based on `HOST_NAME` not starting from `localhost`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to play with the RegEx in the Rewrite Rule a little and change it to:

`RewriteRule ^(?!localhost)(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

`(?!localhost)` is a regEx which means ***NOT* localhost**.